# SimpleXML get certain value based on a field

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to get the url of PRINT_POSITION_URL based on PRODUCT_NUMBER.

For product with product number 7375-**06** i want to get PRINT_POSITION_URL color=**"06"**, for product with product number 7375-**04** i want to get PRINT_POSITION_URL color=**"04"** etc.

These two values are in different XML files which i am getting them from url and they are related with a field PRODUCT_PRINT_ID.

Here is my first XML file(products.xml):

```
<PRODUCTS>
  <PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT_NUMBER>7375-06</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
    <PRODUCT_NAME>Soft ball</PRODUCT_NAME>
    <PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>40002010</PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>
  </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

And here is my second XML file(print-info.xml)

```
<PRINTINGINFORMATION>
  <PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT>
     <PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>40002010</PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>
      <PRINTING_POSITIONS>
        <PRINTING_POSITION>
          <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="04">https://thumb_7375_04.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
          <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="05">https://thumb_7375_05.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
          <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="06">https://thumb_7375_06.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
        </PRINTING_POSITION>
      </PRINTING_POSITIONS>
    </PRODUCT>
  </PRODUCTS>
</PRINTINGINFORMATION>
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
<?php
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
$xmlA = simplexml_load_file('ftp://.../prodinfo_EN.xml');
$xmlB = simplexml_load_file('ftp://.../printinfo.xml');

// create empty output xml object
$final = new simpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PRODUCTINFORMATION></PRODUCTINFORMATION>'); 
$products = $final->addChild("PRODUCTS");

  foreach ($xmlA->PRODUCTS->PRODUCT as $proda) {
    $prodbaseno = (string)$proda->PRODUCT_NUMBER;
    $prodname = (string)$proda->PRODUCT_NAME;
    $prodprintid = (string)$proda->PRODUCT_PRINT_ID;

    // build the output xml
    $prodnew = $products->addChild('PRODUCT');
    $prodnew->addChild('PRODUCT_NUMBER', $prodbaseno);
    $prodnew->addChild('PRODUCT_NAME', $prodname);
    $prodnew->addChild('PRODUCT_PRINT_ID', $prodprintid);

    // find related field from xml file B based on PRODUCT_PRINT_ID
    if ($prodarr = $xmlB->xpath("PRODUCTS/PRODUCT[PRODUCT_PRINT_ID='$prodprintid']")) {
        $prodb = $prodarr[0];

        $prtposns = $prodnew->addChild('PRINTING_POSITIONS');
        foreach ($prodb->PRINTING_POSITIONS->PRINTING_POSITION as $prtpos )   {
            $posnew = $prtposns->addChild('PRINTING_POSITION');
            $posnew->addChild('PRINT_POSITION_URL', $prtpos->PRINT_POSITION_URL);
        }
    }

  }
echo $final->saveXml();
?>
```

And here is the result:

```
<PRODUCTINFORMATION>
  <PRODUCTS>
    <PRODUCT>
      <PRODUCT_NUMBER>MO7375-06</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
      <PRODUCT_NAME>Soft ball</PRODUCT_NAME>
      <PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>40002010</PRODUCT_PRINT_ID>
        <PRINTING_POSITIONS>
          <PRINTING_POSITION>
            <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="04">https://thumb_7375_04.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
          </PRINTING_POSITION>
        </PRINTING_POSITIONS>
    </PRODUCT>
  </PRODUCTS>
</PRODUCTINFORMATION>
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you trying to get the url for the product which has `color="06"` or are you trying to get the value `06` itself because it's the third color, or what? Also, edit the question with more of your code (with all variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a variation on this on your actual xml:

```
<?php
    $stringA = <<<XML
    <PRODUCTS>
      <PRODUCT>
        <PRODUCT_NUMBER>7375-06</PRODUCT_NUMBER>
        <PRODUCT_NAME>Soft ball</PRODUCT_NAME>
      </PRODUCT>
    </PRODUCTS>
    XML;

    $xmlA = simplexml_load_string($stringA);
    $resultA = $xmlA->xpath("//PRODUCTS//PRODUCT");
    $num = $xmlA->xpath("//PRODUCT//PRODUCT_NUMBER/.");
    $tnum = implode($num);

    $stringB = <<<XML
    <PRINTINGINFORMATION>
      <PRODUCTS>
        <PRODUCT>
          <PRINTING_POSITIONS>
            <PRINTING_POSITION>
              <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="04">https://thumb_7375_04.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
              <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="05">https://thumb_7375_05.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
              <PRINT_POSITION_URL color="06">https://thumb_7375_06.jpg</PRINT_POSITION_URL>
            </PRINTING_POSITION>
          </PRINTING_POSITIONS>
        </PRODUCT>
      </PRODUCTS>
    </PRINTINGINFORMATION>
    XML;

    $xmlB = simplexml_load_string($stringB);
    $resultB = $xmlB->xpath("//PRODUCT//PRINT_POSITION_URL[@color=substring-after('{$tnum}','-')]/text()");

    // create empty output xml object
    $final = new simpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PRODUCTINFORMATION></PRODUCTINFORMATION>'); 
    $products = $final->addChild("PRODUCTS");

     foreach ($resultA as $proda) {
        $prodbaseno = (string)$proda->PRODUCT_NUMBER;
        $prodname = (string)$proda->PRODUCT_NAME;

        // build the output xml
        $prodnew = $products->addChild('PRODUCT');
        $prodnew->addChild('PRODUCT_NUMBER', $prodbaseno);
        $prodnew->addChild('PRODUCT_NAME', $prodname);

    foreach ($resultB as $prtpos )   {
          $prodnew->addChild('PRINT_POSITION_URL', $prtpos);
        }

      }

    echo $final->saveXml();
    ?>
```

Output is the one in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've made a mistake on my question. I didn't realise that i should mention that i'm getting the data from two different XML files. I've updated my question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I must mention that i'm getting values from two different XML files based on one related field. I've tried your code but it's not working properly. I've updated my question again because my php code wasn't working. You can check it again.

Comment: After trying to find for a solution based on your answer i found out that `$resultB = $xmlB->xpath("//PRODUCT//PRINT_POSITION_URL[@color=substring-after('{$tnum}','-')]/text()");` isn't working. If i replace `[@color=substring-after('{$tnum}','-')]` with the product number for example `[@color=substring-after('MO7375-06','-')]` outputs the right result. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Billy `$tnum` is a variable inserted into the xpath expression. Some php engines use it without the curly braces; try it that way and see if it works. But in principle, using it with `'{$tnum}'` is valid.

Comment: I tried removing curly braces and i also tried with brackets(parentheses) but it isn't working. I also tried `[@color=('$tnum')]` and changed the value of `$tnum` (which is the PRODUCT_NUMBER) to 06 and it's working. I believe the problem is with the `substring-after` and the variable `$tnum` together. When i echo the `$tnum` using `substring-after` doesn't seem to work, the output i get is `7375-06`  instead of `06`.

Comment: @Billy - See it in action in this fiddle: https://paiza.io/projects/e/Q0Ktj1QbywiPQkVlmhDkeg

Comment: Your answer doesn't work when there are more products on my $xmlA. Given this code in my question it works so i'm going to accept your answer. Thank you very much for your help so far. I guess the problem is the foreach loop when there are more products and i don't get PRINT_POSITION_URL results.